# c# zedgraph: how to use the cursor property?

Tags: c#, cursor, zedgraph

in ZedGraph, when you mouse over a graph, the cursor changes from the default pointer to a crosshair. i'd prefer the cursor remain the default pointer. but changing it, e.g.

`zedGraphControl1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;`

has no effect either in the designer or in the code.

interesting, i can add:

`zedGraphControl1.UseWaitCursor = true;`

and it will show an hourglass when over the control.  but the following:

`zedGraphControl1.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;`

does not. btw, i'm adding that line into one of the ZedGraph demo programs so i know the program works otherweise. ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
zedGraphControl1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: yup, i'd tried that already. no luck. it still changes to a "cross".

Comment: That's how it has to be right...? but if you add this within the MouseMove event of Zedgraph, then it won't change.....

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment by the accepted answer, but I thought this was worth mentioning:

When using the `MouseMoveEvent` for the purpose of overriding the cursor, return a value of `true` to indicate to ZedGraph that you've completely handled the event.  See snippet from documentation below:

> Return true if you have handled the mouse event entirely, and you do
>   not want the ZedGraphControl to do any further action (e.g., starting
>   a zoom operation). Return false if ZedGraph should go ahead and
>   process the mouse event.

e.g.

```
private bool zedGraphControl1_MouseMoveEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    return true
}
```

If you don't, you may see a flicker effect between the ZedGraph default cursor (cross-hairs) and whatever you select as the overriding cursor.